# Recycler not inflated with VideoPlayerRecyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx, exoplayer

I have been trying to implement a ExpoPlayer subclass on RecyclerView based on this link: https://codingwithmitch.com/blog/playing-video-recyclerview-exoplayer-android/.

I have converted the code to Kotlin and am using the Androidx libraries.

The problem is that although there are no exceptions, my code can not find the subclassed RecyclerView in the layout. Not sure if this is a real clue but when tracing the LayoutInflater, I see that it can't find android.widget.view, android.app.view, or android.webkit.view related to the recyclerview/PlayerView (It looks like the the LayoutInflater sequentially tries to find these view types dring this process)

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.video"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // to use any vector drawables
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        // for view binding :
         //viewBinding = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {

    def glideVersion = "4.9.0"
    def exoPlayerVersion = "2.8.4"
    def androidxSupportVersion="1.1.0"
    def nav_version = "2.3.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // takes over from com.android.support:design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidxSupportVersion"

    // ExoPlayer - playing videos
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoPlayerVersion"

    // Glide - thumbnails images
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.2.0"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // following https://dev.to/anesabml/dagger-hilt-basics-23g8
    //Hilt Dependency Injection
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    // For injecting ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01"
    // For injecting WorkManager
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0-alpha01"

    // ExoPlayer - playing videos
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoPlayerVersion"

    // Glide - thumbnails images
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    // Dynamic Feature Module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    //  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

watch_videos_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data class="WatchVideosBinding">
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        tools:context="org.video.start.StartOptionsActivity">

        <org.video.VideoPlayerRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/video_player_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

VideoPlayerRecyclerView.kt

```
package org.video

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Point
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.*
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.*
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util
import org.video.R


// from https://codingwithmitch.com/blog/playing-video-recyclerview-exoplayer-android/  converted to Kotlin
class VideoPlayerRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RecyclerView(context) {

    private val TAG = "VideoPlayerRecyclerView"

    private enum class VolumeState {
        ON, OFF
    }

    // ui
    private var thumbnail: ImageView? = null
    private var volumeControl: ImageView? = null
    private var progressBar: ProgressBar? = null
    private var viewHolderParent: View? = null
    private var frameLayout: FrameLayout? = null
    private var videoSurfaceView: PlayerView? = null
    private var videoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    // vars
    private var mediaObjects: ArrayList<MediaObject> = ArrayList()
    private var videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = 0
    private var screenDefaultHeight = 0
    private var playPosition = -1
    private var isVideoViewAdded = false
    private var requestManager: RequestManager? = null

    // controlling playback state
    private var volumeState: VolumeState? = null

    init {
        // context = context.applicationContext
        val display = (getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
        val point = Point()
        display.getSize(point)
        videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = point.x
        screenDefaultHeight = point.y
        videoSurfaceView = PlayerView(context)
        videoSurfaceView?.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
        val bandwidthMeter: BandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory: TrackSelection.Factory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        val trackSelector: TrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)


        // 2. Create the player
        videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)
        // Bind the player to the view.
        videoSurfaceView?.setUseController(false)
        videoSurfaceView?.setPlayer(videoPlayer)
        setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON)
        addOnScrollListener(object : OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: called.")
                    if (thumbnail != null) { // show the old thumbnail
                        thumbnail!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }

                    // There's a special case when the end of the list has been reached.
                    // Need to handle that with this bit of logic
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        playVideo(true)
                    } else {
                        playVideo(false)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            }

        })
        addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(object : OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {}
            override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
                if (viewHolderParent != null && viewHolderParent == view) {
                    resetVideoView()
                }
            }
        })

        this.videoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            // override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline?, manifest: Any?, reason: Int) {}
            override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline?, manifest: Any?, reason: Int) {
            }
            override fun onTracksChanged(trackGroups: TrackGroupArray, trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray) {}
            override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {}
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Buffering video.")
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Video ended.")
                        videoPlayer?.seekTo(0)
                    }
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {
                    }
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Ready to play.")
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                        if (!isVideoViewAdded) {
                            addVideoView()
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onRepeatModeChanged(repeatMode: Int) {}
            override fun onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(shuffleModeEnabled: Boolean) {}
            override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException) {}
            override fun onPositionDiscontinuity(reason: Int) {}
            override fun onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters: PlaybackParameters) {}
            override fun onSeekProcessed() {}
        })
    }

    fun playVideo(isEndOfList: Boolean) {

        var targetPosition: Int

        if (!isEndOfList) {
            var startPosition = (getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            var endPosition = (getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()

            // if there is more than 2 list-items on the screen, set the difference to be 1
            if (endPosition - startPosition > 1) {
                endPosition = startPosition + 1
            }

            // something is wrong. return.
            if (startPosition < 0 || endPosition < 0) {
                return
            }

            // if there is more than 1 list-item on the screen
            if (startPosition != endPosition) {
                val startPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(startPosition)
                val endPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(endPosition)
                if (startPositionVideoHeight > endPositionVideoHeight) {
                    targetPosition = startPosition
                } else {
                    targetPosition = endPosition
                }
            } else {
                targetPosition = startPosition
            }
        } else {
            targetPosition = mediaObjects.size - 1
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "playVideo: target position: " + targetPosition)

        // video is already playing so return
        if (targetPosition == playPosition) {
            return
        }

        // set the position of the list-item that is to be played
        this.playPosition = targetPosition
        if (videoSurfaceView == null) {
            return
        }

        // remove any old surface views from previously playing videos
        videoSurfaceView?.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)
        removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView!!)

        val currentPosition: Int = targetPosition - (getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

        val child: View = getChildAt(currentPosition) ?: return

        val holder = child.getTag() as VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter.VideoPlayerViewHolder?
        if (holder == null) {
            playPosition = -1
            return
        }
        this.thumbnail = holder.thumbnail
        this.progressBar = holder.progressBar
        this.volumeControl = holder.volumeControl
        this.viewHolderParent = holder.itemView
        this.requestManager = holder.requestManager
        this.frameLayout = holder.media_container

        videoSurfaceView!!.setPlayer(videoPlayer)

        viewHolderParent!!.setOnClickListener(videoViewClickListener)

        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "RecyclerView VideoPlayer"))
        val mediaUrl: String? = mediaObjects.get(targetPosition).media_url
        if (mediaUrl != null) {
            val videoSource: MediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl))
            videoPlayer?.prepare(videoSource)
            videoPlayer?.setPlayWhenReady(true)
        }
    }

    private val videoViewClickListener = OnClickListener { toggleVolume() }


    /**
     * Returns the visible region of the video surface on the screen.
     * if some is cut off, it will return less than the @videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
     * @param playPosition
     * @return
     */
    private fun getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(playPosition: Int): Int {
        val at = playPosition - (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        Log.d(TAG, "getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight: at: $at")
        val child = getChildAt(at) ?: return 0
        val location = IntArray(2)
        child.getLocationInWindow(location)
        return if (location[1] < 0) {
            location[1] + videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
        } else {
            screenDefaultHeight - location[1]
        }
    }

    // Remove the old player
    private fun removeVideoView(videoView: PlayerView) {
        val parent: ViewGroup? = videoView.parent as ViewGroup
        if (parent == null){
            return;
        }
        val index: Int = parent.indexOfChild(videoView)
        if (index >= 0) {
            parent.removeViewAt(index)
            isVideoViewAdded = false
            viewHolderParent!!.setOnClickListener(null)
        }
    }

    private fun addVideoView() {
        frameLayout!!.addView(videoSurfaceView)
        isVideoViewAdded = true
        videoSurfaceView!!.requestFocus()
        videoSurfaceView!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        videoSurfaceView!!.alpha = 1f
        thumbnail!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    private fun resetVideoView() {
        if (isVideoViewAdded) {
            removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView!!)
            playPosition = -1
            videoSurfaceView!!.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            thumbnail!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    fun releasePlayer() {
        if (videoPlayer != null) {
            videoPlayer!!.release()
            videoPlayer = null
        }
        viewHolderParent = null
    }

    private fun toggleVolume() {
        if (videoPlayer != null) {
            if (volumeState === VolumeState.OFF) {
                Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: enabling volume.")
                setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON)
            } else if (volumeState === VolumeState.ON) {
                Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: disabling volume.")
                setVolumeControl(VolumeState.OFF)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setVolumeControl(state: VolumeState) {
        volumeState = state
        if (state === VolumeState.OFF) {
            videoPlayer!!.volume = 0f
            animateVolumeControl()
        } else if (state === VolumeState.ON) {
            videoPlayer!!.volume = 1f
            animateVolumeControl()
        }
    }

    private fun animateVolumeControl() {
        if (volumeControl != null) {
            volumeControl!!.bringToFront()
            if (volumeState === VolumeState.OFF) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    requestManager?.load(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_gray_24dp, null))
                            ?.into(volumeControl!!)
                }
            } else if (volumeState === VolumeState.ON) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    requestManager?.load(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_grey_24dp, null))
                            ?.into(volumeControl!!)
                }
            }
            volumeControl!!.animate().cancel()
            volumeControl!!.alpha = 1f
            volumeControl!!.animate()
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(600).startDelay = 1000
        }
    }

    fun setMediaObjects(mediaObjects: ArrayList<MediaObject>) {
        this.mediaObjects = mediaObjects
    }


}
```

Fragment

```
package org.video

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import org.video.R
import org.video.databinding.WatchVideosBinding
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

// from https://codingwithmitch.com/blog/playing-video-recyclerview-exoplayer-android/
// Was from MainActivity but logic moved to Fragment
@AndroidEntryPoint
class WatchVideosFragment : Fragment() {

    private val videoViewModel: VideoViewModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var binding: WatchVideosBinding
    var recyclerView: VideoPlayerRecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.watch_videos_layout,
                container,
                false
        )
        this.recyclerView = binding.videoPlayerRecyclerView  <<< comes back null
        initRecyclerView(this.recyclerView)

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(recyclerView: VideoPlayerRecyclerView?) {
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView?.addItemDecoration(VerticalSpacingItemDecorator(10))

        val mediaObjects: ArrayList<MediaObject> = videoViewModel.getWatchMediaObjects()
        recyclerView?.setMediaObjects(mediaObjects)
        recyclerView?.adapter = VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter(mediaObjects, initGlide())
    }

    private fun initGlide(): RequestManager {
        val options: RequestOptions = RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.white_background)
                .error(R.drawable.white_background)
        return Glide.with(this)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (recyclerView != null) {
            recyclerView?.releasePlayer()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

Comment: is the itemCount in the adapter correct?

Comment: The recyclerview comes back null from the databinding before the adapter and items are added.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. When I converted the code to Kotlin there was a reference to Context that I thought was redundant and deleted. My bad! Just for reference my new VideoPlayerRecyclerView is below.

The code also includes some view name changes and I found I needed to include a reference to the resource file because if I didn't I kept getting compile errors saying the R.id.(view names) could not be found. Not sure why that is.

```
package org.video

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Point
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.*

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.*
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util
import org.video.R    
import java.util.*


class VideoPlayerRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    private enum class VolumeState {
        ON, OFF
    }

    // ui
    private var thumbnail: ImageView? = null
    private var volumeControl: ImageView? = null
    private var progressBar: ProgressBar? = null
    private var viewHolderParent: View? = null
    private var frameLayout: FrameLayout? = null
    private var videoSurfaceView: PlayerView? = null
    private var videoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    // vars
    private var mediaObjects = ArrayList<MediaObject>()
    private var videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = 0
    private var screenDefaultHeight = 0
    private var viewContext: Context? = null  //<< Need this. Renamed to avoid name conflict with constructor context name
    private var playPosition = -1
    private var isVideoViewAdded = false
    private var requestManager: RequestManager? = null

    // controlling playback state
    private var volumeState: VolumeState? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        this.viewContext = context.applicationContext
        val display = (getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
        val point = Point()
        display.getSize(point)
        videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = point.x
        screenDefaultHeight = point.y
        videoSurfaceView = PlayerView(this.viewContext)
        videoSurfaceView!!.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
        val bandwidthMeter: BandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory: TrackSelection.Factory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        val trackSelector: TrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)

        // 2. Create the player
        videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)
        // Bind the player to the view.
        videoSurfaceView!!.useController = false
        videoSurfaceView!!.player = videoPlayer
        setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON)
        addOnScrollListener(object : OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: called.")
                    if (thumbnail != null) { // show the old thumbnail
                        thumbnail!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }

                    // There's a special case when the end of the list has been reached.
                    // Need to handle that with this bit of logic
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        playVideo(true)
                    } else {
                        playVideo(false)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            }
        })
        addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(object : OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {}
            override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
                if (viewHolderParent != null && viewHolderParent == view) {
                    resetVideoView()
                }
            }
        })
        this.videoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, manifest: Any?, reason: Int) {}
            override fun onTracksChanged(trackGroups: TrackGroupArray, trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray) {}
            override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {}
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Buffering video.")
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Video ended.")
                        videoPlayer?.seekTo(0)
                    }
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {
                    }
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Ready to play.")
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                        if (!isVideoViewAdded) {
                            addVideoView()
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onRepeatModeChanged(repeatMode: Int) {}
            override fun onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(shuffleModeEnabled: Boolean) {}
            override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException) {}
            override fun onPositionDiscontinuity(reason: Int) {}
            override fun onPlaybackParametersChanged(playbackParameters: PlaybackParameters) {}
            override fun onSeekProcessed() {}
        })
    }

    fun playVideo(isEndOfList: Boolean) {
        val targetPosition: Int
        if (!isEndOfList) {
            val startPosition = (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            var endPosition = (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

            // if there is more than 2 list-items on the screen, set the difference to be 1
            if (endPosition - startPosition > 1) {
                endPosition = startPosition + 1
            }

            // something is wrong. return.
            if (startPosition < 0 || endPosition < 0) {
                return
            }

            // if there is more than 1 list-item on the screen
            targetPosition = if (startPosition != endPosition) {
                val startPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(startPosition)
                val endPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(endPosition)
                if (startPositionVideoHeight > endPositionVideoHeight) startPosition else endPosition
            } else {
                startPosition
            }
        } else {
            targetPosition = mediaObjects.size - 1
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "playVideo: target position: $targetPosition")

        // video is already playing so return
        if (targetPosition == playPosition) {
            return
        }

        // set the position of the list-item that is to be played
        playPosition = targetPosition
        if (videoSurfaceView == null) {
            return
        }

        // remove any old surface views from previously playing videos
        videoSurfaceView!!.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView)
        val currentPosition = targetPosition - (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val child = getChildAt(currentPosition) ?: return
        val holder = child.tag as VideoPlayerViewHolder?
        if (holder == null) {
            playPosition = -1
            return
        }
        thumbnail = holder.thumbnail
        progressBar = holder.progressBar
        volumeControl = holder.volumeControl
        viewHolderParent = holder.itemView
        requestManager = holder.requestManager
        frameLayout = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.watch_video_media_container)
        videoSurfaceView!!.player = videoPlayer
        viewHolderParent!!.setOnClickListener(videoViewClickListener)
        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                viewContext, Util.getUserAgent(viewContext, "RecyclerView VideoPlayer"))
        val mediaUrl = mediaObjects[targetPosition].media_url
        if (mediaUrl != null) {
            val videoSource: MediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl))
            videoPlayer!!.prepare(videoSource)
            videoPlayer!!.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

    private val videoViewClickListener = OnClickListener { toggleVolume() }

    /**
     * Returns the visible region of the video surface on the screen.
     * if some is cut off, it will return less than the @videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
     * @param playPosition
     * @return
     */
    private fun getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(playPosition: Int): Int {
        val at = playPosition - (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        Log.d(TAG, "getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight: at: $at")
        val child = getChildAt(at) ?: return 0
        val location = IntArray(2)
        child.getLocationInWindow(location)
        return if (location[1] < 0) {
            location[1] + videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
        } else {
            screenDefaultHeight - location[1]
        }
    }

    // Remove the old player
    private fun removeVideoView(videoView: PlayerView?) {
        if (videoView?.parent == null) {
            return
        }
        val parent = videoView?.parent as ViewGroup
        val index = parent.indexOfChild(videoView)
        if (index >= 0) {
            parent.removeViewAt(index)
            isVideoViewAdded = false
            viewHolderParent!!.setOnClickListener(null)
        }
    }

    private fun addVideoView() {
        frameLayout!!.addView(videoSurfaceView)
        isVideoViewAdded = true
        videoSurfaceView!!.requestFocus()
        videoSurfaceView!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        videoSurfaceView!!.alpha = 1f
        thumbnail!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    private fun resetVideoView() {
        if (isVideoViewAdded) {
            removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView)
            playPosition = -1
            videoSurfaceView!!.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            thumbnail!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    fun releasePlayer() {
        if (videoPlayer != null) {
            videoPlayer!!.release()
            videoPlayer = null
        }
        viewHolderParent = null
    }

    private fun toggleVolume() {
        if (videoPlayer != null) {
            if (volumeState == VolumeState.OFF) {
                Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: enabling volume.")
                setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON)
            } else if (volumeState == VolumeState.ON) {
                Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: disabling volume.")
                setVolumeControl(VolumeState.OFF)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setVolumeControl(state: VolumeState) {
        volumeState = state
        if (state == VolumeState.OFF) {
            videoPlayer!!.volume = 0f
            animateVolumeControl()
        } else if (state == VolumeState.ON) {
            videoPlayer!!.volume = 1f
            animateVolumeControl()
        }
    }

    private fun animateVolumeControl() {
        if (volumeControl != null) {
            volumeControl!!.bringToFront()
            if (volumeState == VolumeState.OFF) {
                requestManager!!.load(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_grey_24dp)
                        .into(volumeControl!!)
            } else if (volumeState == VolumeState.ON) {
                requestManager!!.load(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_grey_24dp)
                        .into(volumeControl!!)
            }
            volumeControl!!.animate().cancel()
            volumeControl!!.alpha = 1f
            volumeControl!!.animate()
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(600).startDelay = 1000
        }
    }

    fun setMediaObjects(mediaObjects: ArrayList<MediaObject>) {
        this.mediaObjects = mediaObjects
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "VideoPlayerRecyclerView"
    }
}
```